# Placeholder CSS Calling Issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Normally we use this idea (different classes separating with comma) **.Test, .test1 {}** ,  But here it will work fine only we call classes separately.

Why this issue ?
Demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/6AR8n/

```
/* seperate classes  */

#red input:-moz-placeholder{
    color:red;
}
#red input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:red;
}



/* Classes with coma */

#green input:-moz-placeholder, input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:green;
}




<div id="red">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Without Coma" >
</div>
<br>
 <div id="green">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Coma" >
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have to enter the question title into the question body when you've already entered it in the title field.

Comment: They're not the same. The second should be `#green input:-moz-placeholder, #green input::-webkit-input-placeholder` (both sides of the comma must be complete, the `#green` part doesn't carry over automatically).

Comment: The question has two problems, and only one is an exact duplicate.  Please reopen so an answer can be explained properly.

Comment: @juhana- Can you please edit that lnk? http://jsfiddle.net/6AR8n/

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Eh, I didn't think that was relevant to the issue at hand so much as an oversight, but fine.

Comment: @Bolt, sorry to nitpick, I just like when questions are completely solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because browsers are supposed to drop the entire rule when encountering unrecognized selectors. From the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets):

> A selector always goes together with a declaration block. When a user agent cannot parse the selector (i.e., it is not valid CSS 2.1), it must [ignore](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#ignore) the selector and the following declaration block (if any) as well.

This includes prefixed selectors, like `:-moz-placeholder` and `::-webkit-input-placeholder` in your example, because a browser isn't supposed to attempt to parse a prefix that it doesn't support; to a certain parser, foreign prefixes are just as invalid as any other syntax error.

Also, as mentioned in the comments the `#green` part needs to be replicated on both selectors in your comma-separated group, like so:

```
#green input:-moz-placeholder, #green input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color:green;
}
```

But this is completely irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: Also, take into account that the `:-moz-placeholder` pseudoclass will be deprecated in favor of the `::-moz-placeholder` pseudoelement as of Firefox 19. By the way, prefixed features are not future-proof. Currently, it's better to remove `placeholder` attribute via JavaScript and then emulate its functionality with JavaScript with ability to style it future-proof way.

Comment: @Marat Tanalin: "the `:-moz-placeholder` pseudoclass will be deprecated in favor of the `::-moz-placeholder` pseudoelement as of Firefox 19" **FINALLY.** That has bothered me for ages. Do you have any relevant links?

Comment: In practice it typically does not matter whether some feature is used as pseudoclass or pseudoelement on syntax level. ;-) Links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-placeholder ; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_19_for_developers ; https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737786 . P.S. It's a shame that it's impossible to insert new lines in StackOverflow comments.

Comment: @Marat Tanalin: It bothers me because of the inconsistency, and also because it can lend itself to specificity problems too. Also, a pseudo-element makes more sense. Both also behave very differently in terms of DOM/CSS...

Comment: I don't use this prefixed stuff due to it's future-unproofness, so didn't encounter such issues as for placeholder. But more consistency is better anyway, indeed. One step closer to its standardizing.