# Why do I have to separate the -input-placeholder css tag for each browser?

Tags: html, css

I tried setting an input placeholder color using the following CSS

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
    input:-moz-placeholder,
    input::-moz-placeholder,
    input::-ms-placeholder {
       color: black;
    }
```

```html
<input placeholder="Some Text">
```

but it does not work as expected in Chrome 59. Instead, I have to write

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
input::-ms-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Some text">
```

Why do I have to write my code like this?

Comment: When the browser sees part of the selector as invalid it invalidates the entire block so just skips it. The part it sees as an invalid selector are the ones for other browsers which it won't recognise.

Comment: `::placeholder {
  color: red;
}` works for me on Chrome and Firefox but not IE. However,  even using `input::-ms-placeholder` doesn't work on IE either. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9p1ssph/)

Comment: see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14082306/862660  I've run into this as well, seems to pop up specifically for placeholder text a lot.